# Regex creation to allow, disallow few characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex, i have this use case:

1. Allow characters, numbers.
2. Zero or one question mark allowed. (? - valid, consecutive question marks are not allowed (??)).

test-valid

?test - valid

??test- invalid

?test?test - valid

???test-invalid

test??test -invalid

3. Exlcude $ sign.

> [a-zA-Z0-9?] - seems this doesn't work

Thanks.

Comment: You should be more concise. Only **one** question mark or **No consecutive** question marks? So, again, how many question marks? Because, if you ask me, if only one is allowed, there's no need to specify consecutiveness.

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code that you've tried, show the errors you got, and the effort you made. SO is NOT a: write code service.

Comment: Try `/^\??[A-Z0-9]+(?:\?[A-Z0-9]+)*\??$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regular expression: 
 `^(?!.*\?\?)[a-zA-Z0-9?]+$`

1. first we're using `Negetive lookahead` - which allows us to exclude any character which is followed by double question marks (`Negetive lookahaed` does not consume characters)
2. Since question mark has special meaning in regular expressions (`Quantifier` — Matches between zero and one times), each question mark is escaped using backslash.
3. The plus sign at the end is a `Quantifier` — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

[You can test it here](https://regex101.com)

Comment: `@Roko C. Buljan` my mistake fixed

Comment: If you already use `*` in `.*` ...than why the `?` in `.*?`

Comment: Also, if you want to save a couple of bytes: `/^(?!.*\?\?)[0-9A-Z?]+$/i` with the *Case Insensitive* flag.

Comment: It did work, thanks a lot, please share some explanation, if possible, thanks again.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 simply paste the code into regex101.com and read the explanation on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Your description can be broken down into the regex:

```
^(?:\??[a-zA-Z0-9])+\??$
```

You say characters and your description shows letters and numbers only, but it's possible `\w` (word characters) may be used instead - this includes underscore

It's between `^` and `$` meaning the whole field must match (no partial matches, although if you want those you can remove this.  The `+` means there must be at least one match (so empty string won't match).  The capturing group (`(\??[a-zA-Z0-9])`) says I must either see a question mark followed by letters or just letters repeating many times, and the final question mark allows the string to end with a single question mark.

You probably don't want capturing groups here, so we can start that with `?:` to prevent capture leading to:

```
^(?:\??[a-zA-Z0-9])+\??$
```

**Matches**

```
test  
?test  
?test?test  
test?
```

**Doesn't match**

```
??test
???test
test??test
test??
<empty string>
?
```

Comment: Ah true, although that's not listed as one of the test cases.. easily remedied

Comment: Now, after your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63588728/revisions)  this will not work for "`?`"

Comment: It's not clear from the description a lone question mark should be included (certainly a question mark surrounded by spaces as you've written should not be included)